# Get ref params from Facebook postback response

Tags: facebook-graph-api

**Goal** - Link my website to my bot.

I'm trying to add a link that sends a user to my bot with the FB m.me Links [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/m-me-links#parameters). I have a `get_started` button that I made using a `POST` request to like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "get_started": {"payload": "get_started"}
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

When a user (me) taps the get stared button the response does not contain any ref params like the docs say it should.
This is the returned response data:

```
 { 
  sender: { id: '1111' },
  recipient: { id: '2222' },
  timestamp: 1572811674525,
  postback: { title: 'Get Started', payload: 'get_started' } 
 }
```

This is what it should look like:

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PAGE_ID>"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "postback":{
    "payload":"<USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD>",
    "referral": {
      "ref": "ref_data_in_m_dot_me_param",
      "source": "SHORTLINK",
      "type": "OPEN_THREAD",
    }
  }
}
```

Where are the ref params? What am I doing wrong?

**Possibility?**: I haven't been able to get any test users to work so I am the only user. Not sure if the ref params are maybe not sent since I am the admin?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs criticality again I realize these ref params not necessary, and they are in fact passed via the request my *me*, the user. They are not auto generated, which I thought because of:

> we will deliver the passed ref param as part of the postback event

They are not also necessary to complete the linking process either.

To get the response to appear like I post above, this is HTML to put in an `a` tag or equivalent, with ref equaling `test` here:

```
http://m.me/<PAGE_NAME>?ref=test
```

*Then* the request returned on a postback with have the refs:

```
referral: { source: 'SHORTLINK', type: 'OPEN_THREAD', ref: 'test' }
```